# ggplot2 graph into pdf, no pdf creating, why?

Tags: pdf, ggplot2

I can't see a problem i have a file 
https://filebin.net/m7q40d1g7ffn6426
and I am using ggplot2 to create a table

```
library(plyr)
library(lattice)
library(Rmisc)#summarySE
library(ggplot2)

pdf("Si.pdf")
IDs<-unique(generegion_subset_melt$X1)
for (i in 1:length(IDs)){
 temp <- generegion_subset_melt[(generegion_subset_melt$X1)==IDs[i],]

 temp <- summarySE(temp, measurevar="value", groupvars=("Category"))


  p <-ggplot(temp, aes(x=Category, y=value, fill=Category))+
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-se, ymax=value+se),
                 colour="grey", width=.2,                    # Width of     the error bars
              position=position_dodge(.9))+
ggtitle(IDs[i])

}
dev.off()
```

why the pdf has so pages? when i try to check single protein with this code it works...
please help!

Comment: Try adding `print(p)` to the end of your loop?

Comment: thanks, it worked. i knew it is missing something :P